# Using Rules to Update the Data of a Relations Endpoints (Referenced Entities)

Tags: 7, rules, entities

I have a [Rule](http://drupal.org/project/rules) which triggers on a [Relation](http://drupal.org/project/relation) update. It then checks for the Entity type of the first endpoint of the Relation. Then checks for a specific field. When I try to set an action to change this specific field, I get these errors related to the **Revision ID** which I can't seem to figure out.

Notice: Undefined property: stdClass::$revision_id in drupal_write_record() (line 7030 of ...\www\includes\common.inc).

Notice: Undefined property: RedhenContact::$revision_id in EntityAPIController->saveRevision() (line 525 of ...\www\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.controller.inc).

Notice: Undefined index: revision_id in EntityAPIController->saveRevision() (line 528 of ...\www\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.controller.inc).

Notice: Undefined index: revision_id in EntityAPIController->saveRevision() (line 533 of ...\www\sites\all\modules\entity\includes\entity.controller.inc).

DatabaseTransactionNoActiveException: in DatabaseConnection->rollback() (line 1024 of ...\www\includes\database\database.inc).

Simply put, I need a specific field on an Entity to update when a related **Relation** is updated. This seems simple, but for some reason I cant get it worked out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in case someone happens upon this, I did find a patch that provided the solution for this error. Turns out the Redhen module had some revision conflict with the entity API, so this [patch here fixed the error](http://drupal.org/node/1592686#comment-6936186), and it should be included in further Redhen updates